# Build failure in data driven framework while using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, data-driven-tests

**Jenkins pipeline build is failing because of following error. I have added dependencies and plugins but still error is not going while using mvn test command in the pipeline.
The same code is working properly through Maven project job. **

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) on project : C:\Users\new\.jenkins\workspace\Pipeline\target\test-classes\dataSheet\webFormstestData - Copy (2).xlsx (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: The problem is: `(Access is denied) `...

Comment: @khmarbaise
How to resolve the same?

Comment: CI on Windows... love it!

Comment: Please can anyone share solution?